# Multiple SOAP endpoints with one namespace & localpart

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services, soap

I created a SOAP web service server with SpringBoot and I was able to successfully create one endpoint.
However, I cannot create multiple endpoints and access them with different URLs.
I want to handle the process by URL to access.

The SOAP message received by each endpoint has the same schema. (Namespace and localpart are the same !!!)
And I don't want to make the WSDL public.

For example.

userA sends the following SOAP message to the following URL: http://soap.example.com/ws/userA

```xml
<S:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <testsoap:post
            xmlns:testsoap="http://soap.example.com/">
            <testsoap:message>
                I am UserA
            </testsoap:message>
        </testsoap:post>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

userB sends the following SOAP message to the URL: http://soap.example.com/ws/userB

```xml
<S:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <testsoap:post
            xmlns:testsoap="http://soap.example.com/">
            <testsoap:message>
                I am UserB
            </testsoap:message>
        </testsoap:post>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The source code is as follows:

```java
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    CustomConfig customConfig;

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet>(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }
}
```

I want to access at http://soap.example.com/ws/userA

```java
@Endpoint
public class SoapRequestEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://soap.example.com/";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "post")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<PostResponse> postForA(MessageContext messageContext) {
        // do something for userA
    }
}
```

I want to access at http://soap.example.com/ws/userB

```java
@Endpoint
public class SoapRequestEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://soap.example.com/";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "post")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<PostResponse> postForB(MessageContext messageContext) {
        // do something for userB
    }
}
```

Comment: While I haven't used Spring Boot yet to expose SOAP services, I had to design a SOAP service in the past that made use of multiple endpoints to separate concerns. The  [sample WSDL](https://github.com/RovoMe/CamelCxfJetty/blob/master/src/main/resources/wsdl/test.wsdl) is used by a Camel-CXF setup (project is outdated though). Not sure if it can help to spot setup issues within your WSDL configuration or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to create an additional Wsdl11Definition method in the WebServiceConfig class and annotate the method with @Bean(name = "UserB").

You have only shown a snippet from your WebServiceConfig class, I am assuming that this is absent from the class.

Your class should look similar to this:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomConfig customConfig;

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet>(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }
}

@Bean(name = "userA")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema [randomMethodSchema]) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("userAPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://soap.example.com/");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema([randomMethodSchema]);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

@Bean(name = "userB")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition2(XsdSchema [randomMethodSchema]) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("userBPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://soap.example.com/");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema([randomMethodSchema]);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema [randomMethodSchema]() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource([schema name].xsd));
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Sorry for lack of knowledge.
Please tell me a little more.
1-
What does randomMethodSchema () mean?
2-
How should I define @Endpoint Class?

Comment: The randomMethodSchema() is just an arbitrary name I came up with for my method name. You can give it any name you choose. (I have updated my answer to show this)

Comment: Your current @Endpoint class will create two operations(postForA & postForB) for both URLs (soap.example.com/ws/userA & soap.example.com/ws/user). if that is what you want, then no need to change what you have. If it isn't, which I suspect is the case, I'm not sure how to about that. You might need another endpoint class for the second URL or find a way to link what you currently have to each bean in the WebServiceConfig

Comment: Ok this way you can publish the same WSDL on with two different port names. But it does not solve the problem of the question as both Endpoints still share the same namespace and localPart spring gives an ApplicationContextException: Cannot map endpoint ... there's already endpoint ... mapped. Was anyone really able to solve the problem to serve two endpoints with same wsdl using different urls?