# Spring-WS: Route a SOAP request through two different endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web-services, soap

I have a `SOAP` endpoint which processes XML requests by identifying the unmarshalled object and then using appropriate handlers. Now, I am trying to make a new endpoint and handler method which would handle the same request differently. From what I understand, `Spring-Webservices` (or SOAP for that matter) doesn't have a RESTful-kind of routing for requests.

**Can I route a SOAP request through two different endpoints with a URL suffix or something in the API path (kind-of RESTful) ?** The namespace, localpart, etc all being same. If not, is there a way ?

SO doesn't seem to have working answers on this topic, tried this:
[How can i have two separate web services with identical name space and local name requests be routed to different end points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369701/how-can-i-have-two-separate-web-services-with-identical-name-space-and-local-nam)

[Multiple SOAP endpoints with one namespace & localpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901622/multiple-soap-endpoints-with-one-namespace-localpart?rq=1)

Any approach/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: If they are the same request, how would you know what to do? That will ofcourse not work as they need to be unique.

Comment: @M.Deinum 
Actually, I want to differentiate at the URL path itself if possible, so that I can have two methods for two ways. (improved problem description in the post)

Comment: The solution in your first linked answer should work. Or just deploy 2 `MessageDispatcherServlet` instances mapped to different base URLs (`/service1` and `/service2`) and each having a dedicated endpoint for what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned approaches in the question didn't work for me, so I used a mixed approach - made a RESTful api for the new endpoint with a different suffix in the url. I read the payload as a string and used marshallers to validate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you need to execute different business logic methods depending on the `flag` value. Well, the most straightforward approach is to use an `if` statement directly inside the endpoint. If you want to call different `API` (controllers) methods, you can take a look at [Spring Functional Endpoints](https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-framework-docs/docs/spring-web-reactive/webflux/webflux-fn.html). Though I'm not sure they are integrated with SOAP